# Mavenプロジェクトでターゲットのjarにはライブラリを含めたくない

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Mavenプロジェクトで開発を行っていますが、以下のことを実現したいのですが可能でしょうか。

1. 基本的に開発中はMavenで依存関係を解決したい
2. 最終的な成果物のjarには、あるライブラリのjarを含めたくない
3. ビルドパスを起動オプションまたは環境変数から追加したい

上記１については通常のMavenの使い方なので可能です。
２については方法を見つけることができませんでした。
３につてもどのようにすればよいのか見当がつきませんでした...

当該アプリケーションがインストールされるPCにはすでに依存関係のあるライブラリがいくつか配置されています。
しかし、PCによってCドライブやDドライブであったりするため、ビルドバスを起動時に変更したいのです。

- OS：Windows
- 開発環境：Eclipse
- 開発言語：Java
- フレームワーク：Spring boot

Comment: 1つのjarの中に必要な依存ライブラリが全て含まれてしまっているjarのことをExecutable-JAR, Fat-JAR, Uber-JARなどと呼んだりするのですが、デフォルトのMavenのpackaging処理ではそのようなjarは生成されません(デフォルトだと、まさにEarleyJPさんが望まれているような形になります)。
おそらく何かpluginが使用された結果そのような成果物が生成されていると思われますので、`pom.xml`がどのようになっているのか(何のpluginを使用しているのか)可能な範囲で開示した方が回答が集まりやすくなるかと考えます。
ちなみに、もし[`Spring Boot Maven Plugin`](http://qiita.com/skinoshita/items/b2c48659b977b26b1eec#33-spring-boot-maven-plugin%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A)を使用されているのであれば、[こちらの設定方法](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html)で除外対象を指定できるようです。

Comment: そうだったのですね。話がそれるのですが、今までの経験上ほとんど、そのExecutable-JARを作ってきたのですが、あるべき姿はよく使うライブラリはどこかに置いといて、クラスパスを指定してあげるものなのでしょうか。

Comment: あるべき姿はどんな用途／環境でJARを実行したいかによるので一概に言えないですが、今までのエンタープライズではだいたいアプリのJARはコンテナに載せて動かすので、Executable-JARは作らなかったですね。ただし、最近のSpring Bootみたいなマイクロサービスの作り方では、逆にExecutable-JARが普通じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: 貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。他サービスと疎結合という点ではExecutable-JARの方が今風なのかなと感じました。なお、特定のライブラリを除外する方法はyukihaneさんにご教示いただいた通りの方法でできました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. 最終的な成果物のjarには、あるライブラリのjarを含めたくない
   コメントにてご教示いただいた通り、pom.xmlのbuildタグ内でexcludes指定する。
   また、今回は除外したいライブラリがMavenリポジトリで管理されておらず、ファイルサーバに配置しているjarをpom.xmlでmaven-install-pluginを利用してコピーしていた。
   その場合、ターゲットjarにもライブラリが同梱されるが、dependencyタグにsystemPath指定したところ、同梱されないようになった。
3. ビルドパスを起動オプションまたは環境変数から追加したい
   jarの起動時にjavaコマンドにて-jarオプションで起動していたが、-classpathオプションで起動するようにした。ただし、Spring Bootにおいて、メインクラスはorg.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncherだった。